# How to avoid using loops in this algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, r, loops, apply

I try to avoid the loops in R, but it seems that I have to use it some times:

```
X=rnorm(100)
Y=matrix(rnorm(200*100),ncol=100)
Beta=function(y,period){  # y is a vector, maybe one row of Y
  num.col=length(y)-period+1
  ret=matrix(NA,1,num.col)  # store the result
  for(i in period:(length(y))){
    lm.sol=lm(y[(i-period+1):i]~X[(i-period+1):i])
    ret[i-period+1]=lm.sol$coefficients[2]
    }
  return(ret)
}
beta.30=apply(Y,1,Beta,period=30)
beta.30=t(beta.30)
```

I try to avoid the loops by using `apply`, but there is still a `for` loop in function `Beta`, and the calculation speed is not fast enough, is there any methods to avoid the `for` loop in this algorithm? Or any methods to speed up the algorithm?

Thanks!

One way I can think about is to compile the `Beta` function by:

```
require(compiler)
enableJIT(3)
```

but still not fast enough, I think I need to modify the algorithm itself.

`lm.fit` is helpful! It greatly improve the speed.

```
Beta1=function(y,period){
  num.col=length(y)-period+1
  ret=matrix(NA,1,num.col)
  for(i in period:(length(y))){
    A=matrix(c(rep(1,period),X[(i-period+1):i]),ncol=2)
    lm.sol=lm.fit(A,y[(i-period+1):i])
    ret[i-period+1]=lm.sol$coefficients[2]
  }
  return(ret)
}
system.time(apply(Y,1,Beta,period=30))
user system elapsed
19.08 0.00 19.08
system.time(apply(Y,1,Beta1,period=30))
user system elapsed
1.09 0.00 1.09
```

Comment: `I try to avoid the loops by using apply`. NO! apply is just a loop with no side effect! and for is not slow in R! This is a myth!

Comment: Loops in R are **not** slow. Have you even bothered to profile your code to see where the bottleneck is? An obvious speed up would be to use `lm.fit` instead of the convenience sugar of the formula interface given by `lm`.

Comment: Indeed: using a profiler indicates that 99.4% of the function's time is spent within the `lm` function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! `lm.fit` is helpful. But how to find that 99.4% of the function's time is spent within the `lm` function?

Comment: : Embarrassed: Didn't know about r profiling.  Thanks for the info R gurus.  Very handy.

Comment: To clarify, usually people say loops are slow in R because they're MUCH MUCH slower than vector operations.  This is true whether it's `for`, or `apply`.  So, they are slow, there's just not much to speak of between `for` and `apply` family functions.  And, if you need a loop, as you can see here, it's not always the source of a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Details [here](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2008-1.pdf)